# Accessing asp.net session in Multi threaded / ThreadPool Thread

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, multithreading, session

I am trying the access the ASP.Net session in the ThreadPool thread. 
The page execution will complete, but Thread will execute for another 5-10sec.

Code looks like below

```
 Dim tContex As HttpContext = HttpContext.Current
 ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf ThreadPoolCallBack, tContex)
```

The Method like below

```
Public Sub ThreadPoolCallBack(ByVal threadContext As Object)
    HttpContext.Current = CType(threadContext, HttpContext)
   Dim userId As Integer = HttpContext.Current.Session("userId")
    DoProcess()
End Sub
```

In ThreadPoolCallBack method I am able access HttpContext and Request param variables, but I am unable to access the Session variables as I am losing Sessions. *Session becoming Null/Nothing in HttpContext.Current**.

**Is there any way to access ASP.Net sessios in another thread.**

Comment: where do you put the `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way.

Pass the session variable instead.

## Code

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf ThreadPoolCallBack, HttpContext.Current.Session)
```

## Method

```
Private Sub ThreadPoolCallBack(ByVal threadContext As Object)
    Dim session = CType(threadContext, HttpSessionState)
    If (session IsNot Nothing) Then
        Dim userId As Integer = session("userId")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not going to work, as I am working on existing code which directly needs access to the Session. I cannot modify existing code base.